# 'Ended' HTML5 event is not binded on elements created after binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I'm working on some online mp3 playlist solution and I have some strange problem. I want to bind 'ended' event on all audio elements that exist or will exist in the future. The strategy is to append new audio element once existing element play ends. The code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id='audio_content'>
<audio class='playable' controls >
  <source  rel='1' src="/files/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</audio>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(".playable").on('ended',function(){
  var id = $(this).find('source').attr('rel');
  $("#audio_content").append("<audio class='playable' controls ><source rel='"+(parseInt(id)+1)+"' src='/files/"+(parseInt(id)+1)+".mp3' type='audio/mpeg'/></audio>");
  $("[rel="+(parseInt(id)+1)+"]").closest('audio')[0].play()
});

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Actually event is binded only on first element, and the second element that is appended inside the event is not binded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : instead of binding event try to change src of the audio, also wrap this script inside `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".playable").on('ended',function(){
      var source = $(this).find('source');
      var id = $(source).attr('rel');
      var newId = parseInt(id)+1;

      //update rel and src
      $(source).attr('rel',newId);
      $(source).attr('src',"/files/"+newId+".mp3");
      $(this)[0].load()
      $(this)[0].play()
    });
});
```

Comment: It is strange, but this way event is not binded at all, even on the first element that exist before the binding :/

Comment: try to put this script inside `document.ready` as updated in answer

Comment: Same thing. It is not binded at all :/

Comment: try replacing `$("#audio_content").on('ended','.playable',function(){` with `$(document).on('ended','.playable',function(){`

Comment: Still no. Seems that this way of binding is not supported by audio element at all.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582918/how-to-correctly-bind-the-html5-ended-event-to-any-future-jquery-produced-el) here OP says he is updating sources of the file and not elements. You can try the same. Let me update my answer and you try it.

Comment: Well thanks for the assistance. Your solution worked fine. The only 2 things that I change are the last lines: 
$(this)[0].load();
$(this)[0].play()